# How do you say love phrases in French?

Tags: expressions

I am getting a custom necklace and want the back to say something like “madly in love” or “falling even more in love” or something to that regard. Can someone give me some French (short) phrases that are cute? I want to have a necklace that symbolizes how much I love my boyfriend!

Answer (score 4):

*Note that (m) and (f) signify options for whether you are male or female.*

---

Somewhat trite:

> - Amour, toujours…

Common, rather trite:

> - Je t'aime à la folie
> - Mon coeur ne bat que pour toi
> - Je t'aime à l'infini

A little long:

> - Tu fais battre mon coeur, je serais perdu (m) / perdue (f) sans toi

Not for the back of the necklace unless you also have a passion for chocolate and teddy bears:

> - Moi sans toi c’est comme une tartine sans Nutella
> - Notre amour est le plus doux des nounours

Intellectual:

> - Tu es mon évidence, le pourquoi de mon existence
> - Même avec un miroir, je refuse de te partager. (*Chairil Anwar*, an Indonesian writer)

Literal translations of “madly in love” and “falling even more in love”:

> - Fou (m) / Folle (f) d'amour (pour toi)
> - Tous les jours plus amoureux (m) / amoureuse (f)

Answer (score 3):

By far, the most common phrase used in that context is:

> ***+ qu'hier, - que demain*** (more than yesterday, less than tomorrow).

It is excerpted from a Rosemonde Gérard's poem that reads:

> *C’est vrai, nous serons vieux, très vieux, faiblis par l’âge,
>
>   Mais plus fort chaque jour je serrerai ta main
>
>   Car vois-tu chaque jour je t’aime davantage,
>
>   Aujourd’hui plus qu’hier et bien moins que demain.*

Answer (score 2):

You can also use for "madly in love":

> fou amoureux/folle amoureuse

Or perhaps silently less cute:

> fou/folle d'amour

Answer (score 0):

Follement amoureux/se, dingue d'amour (familier)